# Kafka consumer does not fetch new records when using topic pattern and large messages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I hope someone of you can help me.

I'm using **spring boot 2.3.4** with **spring kafka 2.5.6**. I recently had to reset an offset and saw some strange behavior. We consumed the messages, but after every X (variating) messages we had a timeout of 10 seconds before the consumption continued.

This is my configuration:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    consumer:
      enable-auto-commit: false
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      heartbeat-interval: 1000
      max-poll-records: 50
      group-id: kafka-fetch-demo
      fetch-max-wait: 10000
    listener:
      type: single
      concurrency: 1
      poll-timeout: 1000
      no-poll-threshold: 2
      monitor-interval: 10
      ack-mode: manual
    producer: 
      acks: all
      batch-size: 0
      retries: 0
```

This is an examle listener code:

```
  @KafkaListener(id = LISTENER_ID, idIsGroup = false, topicPattern = "#{demoProperties.getTopicPattern()}")
  public void onEvent(Acknowledgment acknowledgment, ConsumerRecord<byte[], String> record) {
    log.info("Received record on topic {}, partition {} and offset {}",
            record.topic(),
            record.partition(),
            record.offset());

    acknowledgment.acknowledge();
  }
```

**Analysis**

I figured out that the 10 second timeout came from the `fetch.max.wait.ms` property. However I'm not able to figure out why this property applies.

As far as I understand the `fetch-max-wait` property only determines the maximum time the broker waits before providing the consumer with new records even if the `fetch.min.bytes` is not exceeded. (Which in my case is set to the default 1 and should always be fullfilled)
Furthermore I analyzed that this problem only applies when using topic patterns and "larger" messages.

**Reproduction**

I uploaded an demo application on Github to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/kraennix/kafka-fetch-demo.

How I did reproduce it:

1. I put a thousand messages with 17,1 KB per message on a kafka topic.
2. I start my consuming application that listens per topic pattern to this topic. Then you can see this stopping behaviour.

Note: If I do the same with "small" messages (89 Bytes) it works as expected.

**Logs**

In the logs you can see the successful commit, but then the it says **Skipping fetch**

```
2021-01-16 15:04:40.773 DEBUG 19244 --- [_LISTENER-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Commit list: {publish.LargeTopic.2.test-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=488, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}
2021-01-16 15:04:40.773 DEBUG 19244 --- [_LISTENER-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Committing: {publish.LargeTopic.2.test-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=488, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}
2021-01-16 15:04:40.773 TRACE 19244 --- [_LISTENER-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-kafka-fetch-demo-1, groupId=kafka-fetch-demo] Sending OffsetCommit request with {publish.LargeTopic.2.test-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=488, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}} to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2021-01-16 15:04:40.773 DEBUG 19244 --- [_LISTENER-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-kafka-fetch-demo-1, groupId=kafka-fetch-demo] Using older server API v7 to send OFFSET_COMMIT {group_id=kafka-fetch-demo,generation_id=4,member_id=consumer-kafka-fetch-demo-1-cf8e747f-531d-457a-aca8-18960c518ef9,group_instance_id=null,topics=[{name=publish.LargeTopic.2.test,partitions=[{partition_index=0,committed_offset=488,committed_leader_epoch=-1,committed_metadata=}]}]} with correlation id 62 to node 2147483647
2021-01-16 15:04:40.778 TRACE 19244 --- [_LISTENER-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-kafka-fetch-demo-1, groupId=kafka-fetch-demo] Completed receive from node 2147483647 for OFFSET_COMMIT with correlation id 62, received {throttle_time_ms=0,topics=[{name=publish.LargeTopic.2.test,partitions=[{partition_index=0,error_code=0}]}]}
2021-01-16 15:04:40.779 DEBUG 19244 --- [_LISTENER-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-kafka-fetch-demo-1, groupId=kafka-fetch-demo] Committed offset 488 for partition publish.LargeTopic.2.test-0
2021-01-16 15:04:40.779 TRACE 19244 --- [_LISTENER-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-kafka-fetch-demo-1, groupId=kafka-fetch-demo] Skipping fetch for partition publish.LargeTopic.1.test-0 because previous request to localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) has not been processed
2021-01-16 15:04:40.779 TRACE 19244 --- [_LISTENER-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-kafka-fetch-demo-1, groupId=kafka-fetch-demo] Skipping fetch for partition publish.LargeTopic.2.test-0 because previous request to localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) has not been processed
2021-01-16 15:04:40.779 TRACE 19244 --- [_LISTENER-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-kafka-fetch-demo-1, groupId=kafka-fetch-demo] Skipping fetch for partition publish.LargeTopic.1.test-0 because previous request to localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) has not been processed
2021-01-16 15:04:40.779 TRACE 19244 --- [_LISTENER-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-kafka-fetch-demo-1, groupId=kafka-fetch-demo] Skipping fetch for partition publish.LargeTopic.2.test-0 because previous request to localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) has not been processed
```

Answer (score 0):

When there is a change in the Size of the message, you might need to change below 2 Props
heartbeat-interval: 1000
max-poll-records: 50

Your heart beat interval is 1sec and Max poll wait is 10secs. If the size of the message is high and you are processing the consumed messages in the same thread, then Heartbeat check will fail by the time the next Pull triggered. Make sure to process messages by an Executor using Callable.

Increase the Heart Beat Interval to 5 to 10 secs and Reduce Max Poll records to 15 when the messages size is high. Hope, this can help

Comment: Thanks for your answer. AFAIK the heartbeat always runs in the background and not within the polling/processing thread. Moreover I don't think that the max poll records or the general timing should be a problem because the application can process multiple records per milli seconds. So there shouldn't be any overlapping calls.
I also don't see the correlation between this properties and the topics / topicPattern property. (Annoation property `topics` works as expected)

Comment: I agree with Heart beat running in the background. But, It all boils down to Thread contention. If your hear beat thread doesn't get the time slice with your data processing, then obviously there will be a failure.