# Kafka Consumer stopped consuming messages from topic. We are using SmallRye Reactive Messaging connector to fetch records

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, quarkus, mutiny, smallrye-reactive-messaging

Kafka Consumer stopped consuming messages from kafka topic. We are using SmallRye Reactive Messaging connector to fetch records.

When we enabled trace mode for Kafka logs we are getting below trace message.

`[smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0] Fetcher TRACE[org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.prepareFetchRequests()1179]: [Consumer clientId=topic-data-0, groupId=consumer-5] Skipping fetch for partition topic-data-0 because previous request to {{kafka broker address}} has not been processed`

```
[smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0] KafkaConsumer TRACE[org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches()1293]: [Consumer clientId=topic-data-0, groupId=consumer-5] Polling for fetches with timeout 864
```

Comment: Do you have latency between your application and the broker? It seems like the previous "fetch" is timing out. There are a few configuration properties to increase it, however, in general, the default works well. Try to configure `fetch.max.wait.ms` `max.partition.fetch.bytes` and `fetch.min.bytes` to smaller values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65768175/175554 may help