# Kafka consumer stopped consuming topics from third party system

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My consumers stopped consuming topics from a third party system. But They work with internal topics. The topics from the third party system appear in the kafka web view, but are not consumed.

> Skipping fetch for partition because previous request to some-cluster has not been processed

I did some research and increased the heartbeat and max-poll-records, without success.
See: [Kafka consumer does not fetch new records when using topic pattern and large messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65750740/kafka-consumer-does-not-fetch-new-records-when-using-topic-pattern-and-large-mes/65768175#65768175)
and
[Kafka Consumer stopped consuming messages from topic. We are using SmallRye Reactive Messaging connector to fetch records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71634079/kafka-consumer-stopped-consuming-messages-from-topic-we-are-using-smallrye-reac)

How can I further debug or fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

> How can I further debug this problem?

I would take a look at the lowest level, i.e. network connectivity provided by `org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient`. Logging that on trace level is going to show you outbound requests and received responses (or the timeouts received). This should help you identify whether it's something on your side or some kind of backend mis-configuration.